# How add background color using HTML to Doc converter?

Tags: php, html, export

I am using http://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/ to export html page to DOCX document, please anyone tell me how to add background color of any element, DIV, STRONG, TD, TABLE etc.

I tried by following method,

```
<td width=300 bgcolor="#000099"><b>Column 1</b></td>
<span style="color: red; background: silver; mso-highlight: silver;">Here's some data.</span>
<b style="background:#f00;">Heading 1</b>
```

but no success. How can I add background colors to any element?

After some working and R&D, I got some success

I used the file styles.inc and added my array of classes there with index of bgColor, and it works for main `<TD>` but does not work with nested TD, is there any solution?

Comment: Couldn't you just do that to the html before you pass it to the converter?

Comment: Showing what you tried usually gives your question better reception

Comment: i tried by 'code' <th width=450><b style="background:#f00;">Heading 1</b></th> 'code' and 'code'<td width=300 bgcolor="#000099"><b>Column 1</b></td>  'code' and 'code' <span style="color: red; background: silver; mso-highlight: silver;">Here's some data.</span> 'code'

Comment: sorry, i tried to post code, but it is not fine, i hope you will understand code.

Comment: Maybe you should try using css rather than attributes `<td width=300 style="background-color:#000099">`